# load @Setting based on environment profile?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

Can we somehow use `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Setting` to load config for qa and prod profile separately? any work around?

```
@Setting(settingPath = "/settings/index-settings.json")
@Document
public class Data {

} 

resources/settings/qa.index-settings.json
resources/settings/prod.index-settings.json
```

Comment: Why not just use [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)?

Comment: you mean DataQA, and DataProd with two different profiles ? makes sense.. but Data is a large class

Comment: That also sounds like a problem. But yes, I meant having QA and Prod as different profiles. That's the standard way to have alternative configuration for different environments. I have apps with Prod, Staging, QA, LoadTest, Dev, etc etc, profiles.

Comment: I already have different profiles, how do you apply it on settings ? it just takes a path

Comment: also, having @Profile won't work, since Data is not a spring component

Comment: So build out your settings in a `@Profile` annotated bean? eg using `Settings.builder`?

Comment: but then how do i tie it with Data class ?

Comment: I am running into the same situation, did you find any solution?